# Return to continuous footnote increments after using perpage

Tags: footnotes, perpage

The main content of my book requires that the footnotes reset at 1 with each page.

```
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
```

The `perpage` package does this simply and accurately.

However, the **appendix** to the same book should have **continuously incrementing** footnotes.

**How can I switch from per-page footnotes to per-section footnotes, if I am already using `perpage` at the top?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

My first attempt at an answer (at the end of this) did not work, as pointed out by Steven B. Segletes. I thought that it had but my eyesight on footnote numbers failed me.

This one does work.

```
% footprob.tex  SE 596612
\documentclass{book}

\let\rfootnote\footnote  % save normal version of \footnote

\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}

\newcommand{\notperpage}{\let\footnote\rfootnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\textheight}{0.5\textheight}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Perpage}

Text\footnote{Zero}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{One}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{Two}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{Three}

\chapter{Continuous}
\notperpage % revert to normal footnotes

Text\footnote{Zero}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{One}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{Two}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{Three}

\end{document}
```

**This is my original answer. Do not use it**

Try this:

```
% footprob.tex  SE 596612
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\textheight}{0.5\textheight}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Perpage}

Text\footnote{Zero}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{One}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{Two}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{Three}

\chapter{Continuous}
\makeatletter      %%
\FN@perpagefalse   %% turn off perpage numbering
\makeatother       %%

Text\footnote{Zero}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{One}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{Two}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{Three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm still seeing per-page numbering after the ostensible shift.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Now you mention it so do I. The `perpage` sets `\FN@perpagetrue` so I thought that setting it `\FN@perpagefalse`would stop the perpage nunbering. It is obviously more complicated than I thought. Do you have an answer?

Comment: I wish I did.  The recent implementation of `ltxhooks` has deprecated some of the tools I used to use, but I'm not sure I would get it anyhow.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have now provided an answer that, as far as I can tell, does work. Thank you for spotting and reporting the problem with my original answer.

Comment: Thank you @PeterWilson, this solves this for me!